# Customize endpoint mapping in spring-ws

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-ws

I'm implementing a SOAP web service using Spring WS.

Most of my implementation is done using types with @Endpoint annotations and methods in these types with @SoapAction annotations. Some endpoint interceptors also help glue things together.

I'm using Spring exception handling with SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver that enriches the SoapFault with some specific details.

This works very well. But I have a customer requirement that says that I also have to provide customized SoapFaults for those cases where the service is invoked with an invalid soap-action. Meaning, a soap action for which I have no matching @SoapAction annotation.

What happens now is that Spring logs this:

```
[WARN] org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointNotFound No endpoint mapping found for [AxiomSoapMessage {http://www.example.com/myservice/xml.schema/2010/06/01}MyRequest]
```

I get this returned along with a 404 return code from the Jetty server that hosts this web service.

How can I catch these exceptions and add some custom soapfault handling in this situation? It seems like if only org.springframework.ws.NoEndpointFoundException had a @SoapFault annotation, I could have it go through my exception resolver and customize it that way. But it doesn't, unfortunately.

I think I may have to implement some custom "catch-all" endpoint mapping but I'm just not sure how to do this, and how to ensure that mapping to the specific endpoints are attempted first.

Anyone have a suggestion for how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception seems to be thrown from the class [MessageDispatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/MessageDispatcher.html) in the method dispatch:

```
mappedEndpoint = getEndpoint(messageContext);
if (mappedEndpoint == null || mappedEndpoint.getEndpoint() == null) {
    throw new NoEndpointFoundException(messageContext.getRequest());
```

I suggest to extends this class and instead of throwing an exception, you could add a soap fault as such:

```
SoapMessage response = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
String faultString = "any message"
SoapBody body = response.getSoapBody();
SoapFault fault = body.addServerOrReceiverFault(faultString, getLocale());
```

You can take a look [SimpleSoapExceptionResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html) that deals with exceptions on the endpoints.

Comment: I have an ExceptionResolver already, and this is catching all my annotated exceptions very nicely. But I can't catch the spring exception because it is not annotated. Also, I can extend the MessageDispatcher as you suggest, but how do I make Spring use my messagedispatcher class in stead of its own?

Comment: Did you check section 5.3.2 from http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I was iable to switch over to the regular MessageDispatcher servlet and override the undesired behaviour, although it took a few tries. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @VirtualTroll I bumped into your comment as I am trying to do something similar, but I must say I don't understand how to wire everything up just by reading the 5.3.2 docs, it's very brief and doesn't talk about doing it with annotations and not with XML. Do you know if there is some newer docs somewhere? I am reading these:https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/#server